# pmount - omit rules in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab

How use pmount that it omit fstab rules? For example

```
# fstab:
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom  ... (etc.)

# in terminal
pmount /dev/sr0 /media/xxx
# it will omit /media/xxx mount point and it will mount in /media/cdrom
```

Is there any easily solution to mount other mount point that is in fstab.

In this case I must use pmount beacause I mount as regular user and I am not allowed to add any new entry to fstab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pmount` is generally to be used for mounting custom external devices that are **not** in `fstab`. What you experience is a *feature* of `pmount` - a part of its *policy* (see `man pmount`, search for *fstab*). If you want to permit normal users to mount cdrom, you can either comment it out in `/etc/fstab` and use `pmount` **or** set up the cdrom entry in `fstab` so that users are allowed to mount. For the latter, you'd need to use the `user` mount option (see `man fstab` for more details).