# How to write to ext2 image without having root access

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have been able to mount a ext2 image without having root access by adding an entry to /etc/fstab. However, I am not able to modify this image (copy a new file to it) without having sudo permissions. Is there a way to achieve this without having sudo permissions?

Comment: Are you looking for `chown`/`chmod`? If the permissions of the (mounted) filesystem are set accordingly for that user, you should be able to create new files in it.

Comment: write now the permissions are at -rwxrwxr-x 1 aarunkum aarunkum. What should I change it to so that I don't need sudo access to write to this image?

Comment: Is your user "aarunkum"?

Comment: Have a look at `cat /proc/mounts`. Is the volume mounted read-only?

Comment: You were able to edit /etc/fstab without root access? Wow, that's a barn door sized security hole if I ever heard of one.

Comment: no, /etc/fstab/ was edited with root access.

Answer (score 1):

#### `user` option in fstab

I think you just need to add the option `user` to your `/etc/fstab` entry if you want users to be able to mount the entry. For example:

```
/dev/cdrom  /cd  iso9660  ro,user,noauto,unhide
```

#### pmount

Also I think you can achieve what you want using the app [`pmount`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pmount).

*excerpt from man page*

> pmount - mount arbitrary hotpluggable devices as normal user

To mount:

```
$ pmount /dev/sda1 /media/somedir
```

#### References

- [Understanding fstab](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=283131)
- [pmount project page](http://pmount.alioth.debian.org/)
- [pmount - omit rules in fstab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/pmount-omit-rules-in-fstab)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that this was not related to the permissions of the image file actually. It was related to the permissions within the image file. The file system permissions were set only for root. I mounted the image file and did a chown on all the directories within the diskimage making myself the owner. After that I am able to write to it without root permissions. It makes sense to have the permissions to the image file set to root, as that way the image file becomes portable.